# Getting specific parts from a string to another

Tags: php, string, expression

I have a string variable like following

```
$str= '[[["how ","no use","",""],["to ","no use","",""],["solve this","no use","",""]]]';
```

And i want some parts of this string to make another one like following

```
$result="how to solve this";
```

Is it possible to create $result from $str?

Am new to php someone help me to solve this or any idea to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the string is json, you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn that string into an array. Since the whole thing is wrapped in `[]`, [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) is used to shear off the out outer array.

```
$string= '[[["how ","no use","",""],["to ","no use","",""],["solve this","no use","",""]]]';

$result = '';
foreach(reset(json_decode($string)) as $piece)
{
    $result .= reset($piece);
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered the question, make sure you mark this as answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of your string, you could probably use preg_grep to find any substring  matching `["` until the next `"`

```
$regex = '/\\["([^"])"/';
$matches = preg_grep($regex,$str);
$result = implode('',$matches);
```

Note... my regex might be rusty ;-)